# Does anyone know how to implement the AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate methods correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I am trying to coax AVFoundation to read from a custom URL.  The custom URL stuff works.  The code below creates a NSData with a movie file:

```
NSData* movieData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"memory://video"];
```

I've set up a AVAssetResourceLoader object using the following code:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"memory://video"];
AVURLAsset* asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
AVAssetResourceLoader* loader = [asset resourceLoader];
[loader setDelegate:self queue:mDispatchQueue];
```

The dispatch queue is concurrent.

I then try to extract the first frame from the movie:

```
AVAssetImageGenerator* imageGen = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:asset];
CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 600);
NSError* error = nil;
CMTime actualTime;
CGImageRef image = [imageGen copyCGImageAtTime:time
                                    actualTime:&actualTime
                                         error:&error];
if (error) NSLog(@"%@", error);
```

But when I run this but of code I get:

```
2013-02-21 10:02:22.197 VideoPlayer[501:907] Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x1f863090 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x1e575a90 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 268451843.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (268451843)}
```

The implementation of the delegate method is:

```
- (BOOL)resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest
{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:loadingRequest.request.URL];
    [loadingRequest finishLoadingWithResponse:nil data:data redirect:nil];
    return YES;
}
```

Now, my question is, am I implementing the method correctly?  Does anyone know if what I am doing correct?

Thanks.

EDIT:  The movie I am fetching in its entirety is a single frame movie.

Comment: Now it seems that the copyCGImageAtTime:actualTime:error: call doesn't wait for the delegate method to finish (the delegate method is being run in the dispatch queue).  So the question becomes how can I ensure that the data has loaded before the copyCGImageAtTime:actualTime:error call is made?

Comment: See "Preparing an asset for use" on http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html - Your thumbnail generation code should be in a completion handler block.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but my code is correct when I don't need to change the AVAssetResourceLoader object, and when I fetch from a HTTP or FILE type URL.  I can get the video frame.  The problem I am trying to solve is how do I get it from a custom URL.  I was told that AVAssetResourceLoader was the key but I am having trouble using it.

Comment: Is loadingRequest.request.URL equal to @"memory://video"?  If the NSData object is what you want you could circumvent the whole issue by downloading the data using NSURLConnection, writing it to disk and then using `-[AVURLAsset initWithURL:options:]`... although that seems like a subpar solution.

Comment: The URL is correct.  The problem seems to be a race condition between resourceLoader:shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource: and copyCGImageAtTime:actualTime:error:.  The latter finishes before the former completes.  I would expect the delegate method to finish completely before the latter would end.  So I must be using them incorrectly.

Comment: The reason I am trying a custom URL solution is to avoid writing to disk.  The only working solution I have for using the hardware H.264 decoder is to grab a frame, wrap it in a mp4 wrapper, and write it to the disk.  This is SLOOOOW!!!!  I am trying to avoid the disk write.

Comment: Well, it seems like you shouldn't be attempting to get the image until the data is done loading, or at least until the frame at that time has loaded.

Comment: That's true, but I am not sure how I wait for it.

Comment: Two ideas (untested): (1) Look at your AVURLAsset's AVMetadataItems?  If there is an AVMetadataItem that indicates the frame you need is ready (or which frames are ready since they're all the same to you), you could use the completion handler in `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:`.  (2) Use key-value observing to observe changes to your AVURLAsset's playable property, and only get the frame once it is set to `YES`.

Comment: loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler: forces the call of the delegate method resourceLoader:shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource: it completely finishes before the copyCGImage call, but the copyCGImage call still fails :(

Comment: I think `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 600);` is wrong (that would be 0/600th of a second, or 0, which is before the movie starts.)  Try `CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 1);`

Comment: Also, `image` won't be released by ARC, so you need to do `CGImageRelease(image);` when you're done with it.  (This is incidental to your problem, just a memory leak.)

Comment: @Aaron - thanks for your help.  The CMTimeMakeWithSeconds call works when I generate an image from a file url.  I have this code all working when I load from disk, but I am trying to coax it to load from a memory buffer.  I didn't include all my code - I do use CGImageRelease.  Thanks.

Comment: @Cthutu have you made it work?

Comment: I did if I recall, but it turned out that it was much slower than writing out the single frame to the file as a mp4 file and using AVFoundation as normal.  I can remember being very disappointed.  Our solution was to just use JPEGs and forget about H.264.

Answer (score 8):

I have implemented a working version of this method. It took me a while to figure out. But the resulting app now works. Which suggests that the code is okay.

My app includes a media file which I did not want to ship in the package unencrypted.  I wanted to dynamically decrypt the file. (a block at a time).

The method has to respond both to the content request (tell the player what it is loading)
And to data requests (give the player some data).  The first time the method is called, there is always a content request.   Then there will be a series of data requests.

The player is greedy. It always asks for the entire file. You are not obliged to provide that.  It asks for the whole cake. You can give it one slice.

I hand the media player blocks of data. Usually 1 MB at a time.  With a special case to handle the smaller final block.   Blocks are usually asked for in sequence. But you need to be able to cope with out-of-sequence requests too.

```
- (BOOL) resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest
{
    NSURLRequest* request = loadingRequest.request; 
    AVAssetResourceLoadingDataRequest* dataRequest = loadingRequest.dataRequest;
    AVAssetResourceLoadingContentInformationRequest* contentRequest = loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest;

    //handle content request
    if (contentRequest)
    {
        NSError* attributesError;
        NSString* path = request.URL.path;
        _fileURL = request.URL;
        if (_fileHandle == nil)
        {
            _fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
        }

        // fire up the decryption here..
        // for example ... 
        if (_decryptedData == nil)
        {
            _cacheStart = 1000000000;
            _decryptedData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:BUFFER_LENGTH+16];
            CCCryptorCreate(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, [sharedKey cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding], kCCKeySizeAES256, NULL, &cryptoRef);
        }

        NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&attributesError];

        NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
        _fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];

        //provide information about the content
        _mimeType = @"mp3";
        contentRequest.contentType = _mimeType;
        contentRequest.contentLength = _fileSize;
        contentRequest.byteRangeAccessSupported = YES;
    }

    //handle data request
    if (dataRequest)
    {
        //decrypt a block of data (can be any size you want) 
        //code omitted

        NSData* decodedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:outBuffer length:reducedLen];
       [dataRequest  respondWithData:decodedData];
    [loadingRequest finishLoading];
    }


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have similar kind of implementation but I am facing issue sometimes while scrubbing through the video. Sometimes video pixelates or appear green when we scrub back and forth. Have you faced similar issues?

Comment: I got my app to be stable. But the application didn't require scrubbing. I was a little unsure of how to drive the CCCrypto code.

Answer (score 1):

I just wasted 2 hours trying to do something very similar.

Turns out it only works on device, and doesn't work on the iOS Simulator !

I guess AVFoundation in the simulator is somehow "bridged" to the host Mac's AVFoundation. Unfortunately this API isn't available on OS X 10.8 (according to some commits on WebCore it will be available in OS X 10.9), so for now it doesn't work in the simulator.

Comment: I'm stuck with the delegate. I implemented it but for some reason I received the "failed" status. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I implemented my delegate like this: 
- (BOOL)resourceLoader:... {
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample.m4v" withExtension:@""]];
    NSURLResponse* response = [[NSURLResponse alloc]initWithURL:self.url MIMEType:@"video/x-m4v" expectedContentLength:[data length] textEncodingName:nil];
    [loadingRequest finishLoadingWithResponse:response data:data redirect:nil];
    return YES;
}

Answer (score 1):

User NSURLComponent along with the scheme = "enc" in order to call AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate method.

```
let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(url: video_url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
    urlComponents?.scheme = "enc"
let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: (urlComponents?.url)!, options: ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": headers])
    avAsset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "AVARLDelegateDemo loader"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [create an NSURLResponse object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLResponse/initWithURL%3aMIMEType%3aexpectedContentLength%3atextEncodingName%3a) to pass back.  You're passing back `nil`.  Without it, AVAssetResourceLoader has no idea what to do with the data you hand it (that is, it has no idea what type of data it is - an error message, a jpeg, etc.).  You should also really be using `-[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]` and checking for an error before assuming success.

Comment: I tried that - and it didn't work either.  Perhaps it is still something I need anyway.  But what is happening is that the fetching of a frame is ending with an error before the delegate method has finished.  There is nothing blocking on the outcome of the delegate method.  To create the response I use: [[NSURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:loadingRequest.request.URL MIMETYPE:@"video/mp4" expetedContentLength:data.length textEncodingName:nil]

Comment: I don't think the problem is the delegate method (at least not the immediate problem I have to solve) because it is not finishing before the copyCGImageAtTime:actualTime:error: call returns.  There's a synchronisation problem between two threads which I don't know how to solve.

Comment: ~Cthutu, have you found any solution for this.